# Needs to restart Network-Manager to see broadband interface

Tags: network-manager, mobile-broadband

I installed xenial (xubuntu) on my Lenovo x220 and all works well. I also setup my broadband network interface to use T-Mobile and connection works. But after reboot or hibernate I ever have to restart network-manager service to see the broadband interfaces in nm-applet.

What have I to configure to see my broadband device directly after reboot or resume from hibernate?

Comment: Same exact issue here _(Ubuntu & Xubuntu)_, i ended creating a shortcut for _FN + F9_ which executes `pkexec sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service`. Sometimes I also have some WiFi problems if I reboot with it (soft)disabled. Maybe someone can throw some more light into this...

Comment: I also observed this: if enable the option  _autoconnect to this network_ it connects even if is not showing at all. I'm doing my tests with `nmcli radio wwan off && nmcli radio wwan on` and other nmcli commands which seems to be a cleaner solution...